# String split and expand the (vector) at the delimiter: R

Tags: r

I have this vector (it's big in size) `myvec`. I need to split them matching at `/` and create another result vector `resvector`. How can I get this done in R?

```
myvec<-c("IID:WE:G12D/V/A","GH:SQ:p.R172W/G", "HH:WG:p.S122F/H")

resvector

IID:WE:G12D, IID:WE:G12V,IID:WE:G12A,GH:SQ:p.R172W,GH:SQ:p.R172G,HH:WG:p.S122F,HH:WG:p.S122H
```

Comment: Did you try `?strsplit`

Comment: I am a beginner in R. I tried several ways,but could not get it done. I actually need to replicate the columns based on this. Those vectors are the column names and I need to replicate the columns base on the separator.

Comment: Should that be an `"H"` at the end of `resvector`?

Comment: @user277653 In this case show (or a least talk about) what you already tried and where you failed. This show you already tried something before asking for a free code :)

Comment: @BenBarnes you are correct! I have corrected that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this, using `strsplit` as mentioned by @Tensibai:

```
sp_vec <- strsplit(myvec, "/") # split the element of the vector by "/" : you will get a list where each element is the decomposition (vector) of one element of your vector, according to "/"
ts_vec <- lapply(sp_vec, # for each element of the previous list, do
                 function(x){
                     base <- sub("\\w$", "", x[1]) # get the common beginning of the column names (so first item of vector without the last letter)
                     x[-1] <- paste0(base, x[-1]) # paste this common beginning to the rest of the vector items (so the other letters)
                     x}) # return the vector
resvector <- unlist(ts_vec) # finally, unlist to get the needed vector

resvector
# [1] "IID:WE:G12D"   "IID:WE:G12V"   "IID:WE:G12A"   "GH:SQ:p.R172W" "GH:SQ:p.R172G" "HH:WG:p.S122F" "HH:WG:p.S122H"
```

Comment: @user277653, np, glad to help. I added some explanations.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a concise answer with `regex` and some functional programming:

```
x = gsub('[A-Z]/.+','',myvec)
y = strsplit(gsub('[^/]+(?=[A-Z]/.+)','',myvec, perl=T),'/')

unlist(Map(paste0, x, y))
# "IID:WE:G12D"   "IID:WE:G12V"   "IID:WE:G12A" "GH:SQ:p.R172W" "GH:SQ:p.R172G" "HH:WG:p.S122F" "HH:WG:p.S122H"
```

Comment: well, happy to be (small) part of this clever way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
myvec<-c("IID:WE:G12D/V/A","GH:SQ:p.R172W/G", "HH:WG:p.S122F/H")

custmSplit <- function(str){
  splitbysep <-  strsplit(str, '/')[[1]]
  splitbysep[-1] <- paste0(substr(splitbysep[1], 1, nchar(splitbysep[1])), splitbysep[-1])
  return(splitbysep)
}

do.call('c', lapply(myvec, custmSplit))
# [1] "IID:WE:G12D"    "IID:WE:G12DV"   "IID:WE:G12DA"   "GH:SQ:p.R172W"  "GH:SQ:p.R172WG" "HH:WG:p.S122F"  "HH:WG:p.S122FH"
```

Comment: your sol, although very similar to mine, doesn't work : you have to put `substr(splitbysep[1],1,nchar(splitbysep[1])-1)` to obtain the desired result; `substr(splitbysep[1],1,nchar(splitbysep[1]))` is just the same as `splitbysep[1]` ;-)